# Importing Python packages in RStudio QMD

Tags: python, r, rstudio, reticulate

Very new to Python and R, so apologies for probably a very basic question. Attempting to install `numpy` and `pandas` in RStudio .qmd file. I have referenced other similar questions, but I'm continuing to get the same error when I transition from R code chunks to Python code chunks.

RStudio .qmd file:

```
{r, warning=FALSE, output=FALSE, message=FALSE}

library(tidyverse)
library(reticulate)
py_install("numpy", pip=TRUE)
py_install("pandas", pip=TRUE)
```

Everything loads fine with that code. But when I change to Python after and enter this code:

```
{python}
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

I get the following errors in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\reticulate\python\rpytools\loader.py", line 119, in _find_and_load_hook
    return _run_hook(name, _hook)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\reticulate\python\rpytools\loader.py", line 93, in _run_hook
    module = hook()
             ^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\R\win-library\4.2\reticulate\python\rpytools\loader.py", line 117, in _hook
    return _find_and_load(name, import_)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you might need to set your Python environment in RStudio and make sure you `py_install()` into the same env (reticulate tries to auto-select one by default).

Go to *Tools -> Global Options... -> Python* to see which environments are available.

I recommend choosing `r-reticulate` or `r-miniconda`. Depending on your setup.

- https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/1500007929061-Using-Python-with-the-RStudio-IDE
- https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/reference/py_install.html

---

**Other things to try:**

- run `pak::pkg_install("reticulate", upgrade = TRUE)` (see https://github.com/r-lib/pak)
- `reticulate::install_miniconda()`

Comment: Needed to set the python environment! That fixed all the errors. Thank you!